# MqSQL. Записать в ячейку одной таблицы сумму значений нескольких ячеек из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы MySQL:

1. id, object, totalValue
2. id, item, objectId, value

В первой таблице хранится список имеющихся объектов (object) и общий вес каждого объекта (totalValue). Записей будет от 20 до 100.

Во второй таблице хранится список предметов внутри (item), каждый предмет связан с объектом через objectId, у каждого предмета свой вес (value). Записей будет несколько тысяч.

totalValue у объекта с идентификатором id - это сумма всех value у item из второй таблицы с соответствующим objectId.

Необходимо при изменении value предмета во второй таблице обновлять totalValue у соответствующего объекта в первой.

Например:

```
Таблица 1
id | object | totalValue
1  | obj1   | 4
2  | obj2   | 6

Таблица 2
id | item | objectId | value
1  | itm1 | 1        | 2   
2  | itm2 | 1        | 1
3  | itm3 | 2        | 3   
4  | itm4 | 1        | 1
5  | itm5 | 2        | 1
6  | itm6 | 2        | 2
```

На данный момент всё что я придумал - это, после сохранения данных во вторую таблицу, выгружать вторую таблицу в массив, перебирать его в php и результат записывать в первую таблицу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это сделать корректнее?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону сгенерированных столбцов

Comment: *можно ли это сделать корректнее?* Конечно. Это может выполнить триггер... С другой стороны - а нафига оно вообще нужно, поле общего количества в первой таблице, если его данные получаются из данных второй таблицы несложным запросом?

Comment: @Miron Generated column может оперировать только значениями полей текущей записи.

Comment: @Akina в первой таблице будет около 30 записей, а во второй несколько тысяч. При каждой перезагрузке страницы перебирать несколько тысяч записей - не самый лучший вариант, как мне кажется.

Comment: Несколько тысяч записей - это ни о чём... сколько времени кушает суммирующий запрос? Тем более если страница грузится и соответственно запрашивает данные часто - всё закэшится.

Comment: если вы перебирать записи собрались на пхп, то конечно не самый лучший, а подзапрос с суммированием, особенно добавив соответствующие индексы в таблицы, будет весьма быстр. на таких объемах таблицы нет смысла нарушать нормализацию ибо выгода в скорости будет незаметна.

Comment: @teran можете подсказать текст запроса? Или хотя бы на какие функции смотреть. Я в MySQL дно =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в `items` добавляете индекс по полю `object_id`, далее чтобы получить `objects` с суммарным весом будет две стратегии.

a) подзапрос с суммой

```
SELECT  o.id, o.object, 
       (SELECT sum(value) FROM i WHERE i.object_id = o.id) as totalValue
FROM o
# WHERE o.id = ... // фильтрация если нужна
```

б) джойн и группировка

```
SELECT o.id, o.object, sum(i.value) as totalValue
FROM o
INNER JOIN i ON (i.object_id = o.id)
GROUP BY o.id, o.object
# WHERE o.id = ...
```

Если вы выбираете данные для одной записи, то, наверное, первый вариант будет предпочтителен. Если для всех, то второй. Хотя можно и сравнить результаты по скорости, для такого объема таблиц, разницы особой не будет.